# If I declare a semaphore in a malloc'd struct and I free() the struct do i still need to destroy the semaphore?

Tags: c

Pertaining to C programming.

Suppose i do this:

```
struct myStruct
{
    pthread_mutex_t myMutex;
    sem_t mySemaphore;
};
```

`

And i malloc the appropriate size and initialize the Semaphore:

```
myStruct *create_myStruct()
{
    myStruct *temp; 

    temp = (myStruct *) malloc(sizeof(myStruct));
    sema_init(&sema, 0, 0);
    pthread_mutex_init(&(temp->myMutex), NULL);
    return temp;
}
```

Do I still need to manually destroy the semaphore or just calling free will do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to destroy both the mutex *and* the semaphore, and that needs to happen *before* you free the memory. Otherwise you have a resource leak, and your program has undefined behaviour.

You should mentally distinguish between objects and the state they represent on one hand, and the memory in which the object is stored on the other hand. Neither one knows about the other, and both need to be set up and torn down individually (and in reverse order).

Comment: Thank you. I'm guessing the internal structure of a semaphore contains pointers too.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to have a destroy function for any non-trivial structs.

Comment: @Henry: it doesn't matter whether the internal structure contains pointers or not, the issue is that the semaphore is a resource whose interface says it needs releasing. It might just contain a small integer (like a file descriptor is a small integer) that the OS uses to identify that resource. It might contain no reference of any kind to a resource, but the OS holds its address in some structure and removes it when you destroy. It might have no resource that needs freeing, and `sem_destroy` is a no-op, but to permit implementations in which it does do something, you have to call it.

Comment: @SteveJessop Thank you! I'm still a little confused as i thought that you only need to de-allocate dynamically allocated memory. Meaning the underlying structure has pointers to somewhere which dynamically allocated the memory when you call sema_init. Sorry, I'm still learning!

Comment: @Henry: Forget about the memory for a minute. The library mandates that you initialize things before you start using them and that you release them when you're done. You just have to do that. It's not for you to question the API. The memory is a separate issue; it has to be acquired before you set up your objects, and freed after you clean up the objects.

Comment: @KerrekSB ah, i think i get the point you two are trying to make, thank you!