# Implementing a semaphore in a struct, then use malloc() to initialize a struct, will there be futex errors?

Tags: c, struct, semaphore

This is my first time asking questions on stack overflow, if there's anything I did incorrectly, feel free to point it out. Thanks a lot!

In a struct, there's one variable **sem** of type sem_t.

```
struct myStruct
{
    sem_t sem;
}myStruct;
```

In the initialization code of the struct, I write it like this:

```
myStruct* init_myStruct()
{
    myStruct* tmp = (myStruct*)malloc(sizeof(myStruct)); 
    sem_init(&tmp->sem, 0, 1);
    return tmp;
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is the `init_myStruct()` implemented correctly? Will this cause futex errors? Is it required that I declare semaphore **sem** as static variable?
2. The second question comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177753/if-i-declare-a-semaphore-in-a-mallocd-struct-and-i-free-the-struct-do-i-still). Suppose we call `init_myStruct()` in **main**, then we need to free the semaphore **sem** before we free the struct. Assume that the pointer to the myStruct is assigned to **s** in main, then is it correct to simply do `free(&s->sem)` and then we can `free(s)`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a bunch of typos. `temp` should be `tmp`, and `sem_en` should be `sem`.

Comment: Are you thinking of sem_destroy when you say “free” the semaphore?

Comment: I was thinking that the procedure of initializing a semaphore was like calling ```malloc()```. That's why I was asking how to free the semaphore. However, if it's not like calling ```malloc()```, then the semaphore would be freed by simply calling ```free(s)```. @EdmCoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The semaphore can be anywhere in memory. There's no problem with it being in memory allocated using `malloc()`, as long as you destroy the semaphore before freeing the memory, as explained in the answer to the other question.
2. You can only free the same pointer that was returned from `malloc()`. Since you allocated the whole structure, you need to free that as well. So `main()` should do `free(s)`. You can't do `free(&s->sem)` because `&s->sem` is not a pointer that was returned by `malloc()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I probably did not point it out clearly in my question. I was about to ask if I call free(&s->sem), and then free(s) is correct. I will edit my question.

Comment: Why do you want to do `free(s->sem)`? You never allocated `s->sem`

Comment: Oh, I see. I understand what I got wrong here. Thanks a lot!